# Manager and Direct Reports showing in Delve but not in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Hoping one of you fine people can help me here. I'm trying use the graph to access manager and directReports for all employees on the tenant. I have setup my test tenant with myself with a manager and direct report and this shows in Delve as the image below shows:

[image: Delve app showing direct report]

When logging into the Graph Explorer using the same login and clicking directReports I get the following:

[image]

Is this a permissions issue? I've tried different permissions granted to the explorer without success. Below are the permissions I've granted to the explorer and I've also consented to the permissions as admin ( which is the same user I'm logged in as )

Any help is appreciated as I've now spent 2 days trying to resolve this and associated issues. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this situation, are you signed in as the Manager or the person who reports to the manager?

Comment: Thanks for your response Shawn. I was signed in as the manager ( Mark ) but shortly after I posted this worked out what I'd done wrong and had missed setting up Exchange on my test tenant. I'd setup the user profiles / reports / managers etc in SharePoint but not in Exchange. I was unaware this had to be done and after 2 days pulling my hair out in frustration am not likely to forget. Once I setup the manager in Exchange admin all worked as expected. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in my comment above I hadn't setup the manager in Exchange admin, only in SharePoint admin ( user profiles ) so hopefully this helps anyone else who didn't know you had to do this. Once setup in Exchange as well all worked fine.